# Calling .NET from Perl

Tags: .net, windows, perl, ipc

I have a Perl script and needed to call a method that's in a .NET assembly.  I found [this technique](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=392275) but it's quite involved for a one-off Perl script so I didn't use it.  I ended up writing a trivial .NET console app as a wrapper for the call I need and have my Perl script communicate with the wrapper, using `Console.In / Console.Out / IPC::Open2`.

This turned out to be problematic because .NET's `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` method did not seem able to detect the end-of-file on `Console.In`, even after my Perl script closed its end of the pipe!

I ended up hacking a solution that worked for my purposes, but is there a better way to call .NET from Perl?

Comment: I haven't worked with Perl. Having said that, you can export your assembly to be COM visible (tlbexp) and using the COM library from perl?

Comment: Have you had a look at PerlNet? http://docs.activestate.com/pdk/8.0/PerlNET_overview.html

Comment: PerlNet seems to be only for ActiveState right?  I am using Strawberry

Comment: Yes, it's only ActiveState. There's also [PerlSharp](http://razor.occams.info/code/perlsharp/), but that allows you to interface to Perl from .NET (may or may not work in your situation, considering you already wrote a wrapper, it may just be what you need).

Answer (score 3):

> *"StreamReader.ReadToEnd method did not seem able to detect the end-of-file on Console.In"*

You seem to have been able to interface with .NET. But you called [`StreamReader.ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) on a console input. That can be problematic, even without Perl. An excerpt of why this is:

> ReadToEnd assumes that the stream
>   knows when it has reached an end. For
>   interactive protocols, in which the
>   server sends data only when you ask
>   for it and does not close the
>   connection, ReadToEnd might block
>   indefinitely and should be avoided.

Perhaps your code is right, but you need to use a different method for your purpose.

**Edit:**

> *"I ended up writing a trivial .NET console app as a wrapper "*

It seems to me that you try to communicate between the two (Perl and .NET). The protocol you chose (Console.In/Out) may work, but you should use `StreamReader.Read` or `StreamReader.ReadLine` in your .NET application in a loop, that way you can easily detect when the stream is closed. The Read operations will return `null` when they are at EOF.

Alternatively, you can use any method that pleases you in Perl and have it called from .NET. I.e., you inverse the logic and .NET just asks by interfacing with your Perl code, for input. Then you can stick with Perl for your main programming task. You can do this using [PerlSharp](http://razor.occams.info/code/perlsharp/).

Comment: I ended up passing a byte length as a command-line parameter to the wrapper console app, and having the console app call "ReadBlock" instead of "ReadToEnd"

Comment: I don't think switching to Read / ReadLine will work any better then ReadToEnd.  You say the Read operations return null when they are at EOF, but the problem is they can't detect EOF on a pipe.  They would just block when I finish writing, just like ReadToEnd

Comment: @JoelFan: That's not according to the .NET documentation, see the link on ReadToEnd in my post. However, I can do a little test of course, see what comes up. Btw, `ReadBlock` basically works the same as `Read`, it internally calls `Read` anyway, so if that works for you, both approaches should work. Mmm, things considering, I assume only without the EOF-flag ;-)

Comment: The reason ReadBlock works for me is because I am passing the number of bytes to read into my wrapper and feeding that count into ReadBlock. The result of this is that I don't end up invoking the (faulty) EOF detection of StreamReader AT ALL.